# Maximal existence time interval for ODE $x'=2tx^2,$ with I.C $x(0)=\xi.$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

So the first part is simple. We have that

$$\frac{dx}{dt}=2tx^2\implies\int\frac{dx}{x^2}=\int2t \ dt\implies x(t)=\frac{1}{-C-t^2}.$$

The I.C $x(0)=\xi$ gives

$$x(0)=\xi=\frac{1}{-C}\Longleftrightarrow C=-\frac{1}{\xi}.$$

Thus the solution is

$$x(t)=\frac{1}{-\frac{1}{\xi}+t^2}.$$

Now I split this into 3 cases:

- $\xi=0$ gives constant solution $x(t)\equiv0, \ \forall \ t \in\mathbb{R}.$ Thus the maximal interval is $I_{\text{max}}(\xi)=\mathbb{R.}$
- $\xi<0\implies$ $x(t)$ is defined $\forall \ t \in\mathbb{R}$, thus $I_{\text{max}}(\xi)=\mathbb{R}.$
- $\xi>0$. Here is my question. According to the lecture notes, for these strictly positive $\xi$ the solution is only defined for $\xi\in\left(-\frac{1}{\sqrt{\xi}},\frac{1}{\sqrt{\xi}}\right).$ So they also conclude that this is the maximal interval. I beg to differ since $x(t)$ in this case is ONLY undefined at the endpoints of the above interval.

When it comes to this maximal interval, are they looking for an interval $[t_1,t_2]$ that is continuous in between? I then don't understand why they don't simply choose $(-\infty,-1/\sqrt{\xi})$ or $(1/\sqrt{\xi},\infty)$ since both are larger than the above correct maximal interval, however I assume they can let $\xi\rightarrow\infty$ thus obtain the maximal that way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $x(0)= \xi$, the maximal intervall has to contain $0$ !

If $ \xi >0$ we have $0 \notin (-\infty,-1/\sqrt{\xi})$ and $0 \notin (1/\sqrt{\xi},\infty)$

Furthermore: $\xi $ is fixed, thus $ \xi \to \infty$ makes no sense !

Comment: Ah alright, missed the "containing $t=0$"-part. What I meant with $\xi\rightarrow \infty$ was that one could choose an extremely large $\xi$. However, do you agree that the sentence "the solution is only defined for $\xi\in (-1/\sqrt{\xi},1/\sqrt{\xi})$" is wrong? Because it IS defined for other values as well except that the maximal interval can't be outside this since it has to contain $t=0$.

Comment: One more question, if $\xi=0$, isn't $x(t)$ undefined since we are dividing by $0$?

Comment: Your computations above are only valid in the case $ \xi \ne 0.$ If $\xi =0$, the initial value problem has the unique solution $x(t)\equiv0, \ \forall \ t \in\mathbb{R}.$